# Computing row % for group of rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
Name    Category    Amount
ABC     Science     50
ABC     History     -100
XYZ     Science      600
XYZ     Geography    -300
```

And I want a dataframe, that will look like:

```
Name    Category    Amount   Category%
ABC     Science     50        33.33
ABC     History     -100      66.66
XYZ     Science      500      50
XYZ     Geography    -500     50
```

Can you please advise what transformation would work best here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the Category% calculated? It doesn't quite make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not exactly clear, but i guess this is what you want -

```
df['absamt'] = df['Amount'].apply(lambda x:abs(x))
df = df.merge(df.groupby("Name")["absamt"].sum().reset_index(), on="Name", how="left")
df['Ratio'] = df['absamt_x']/df['absamt_y']
```